# Why do my buttons have this outline? css

Tags: html, css

[Button outline picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4no.png)

It appeared when I added box-shadow to btn but doesn't disappear when I take it away.

```css
.btn {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  margin-top: 4px;
  background-color: #6c608c;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  -o-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
  transition: background-color .2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="col span_1_of_3">
  <img src="images/icon.png"></img>
  <h1>SPACECRAFT</h1>
  <button href="/index.html" class="btn">home</button>
  <button href="members/index.html" class="btn">members</button></br>
  <button href="studios/index.html" class="btn">studios</button>
  <button href="contact/index.html" class="btn">contact</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button object uses the `outline` value to indicate that it has focus. This is actually fairly important for keyboard users. But if you want to get rid of it, then you need to do something like this:

```
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Tried that, it's not working though

Comment: It worked with `border: none;` thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to add one more style in your `.btn class` like the following:

```
.btn {

      outline:none;

}
```

---